# Unable to find the node_modules folder in angular project

Tags: angular, node-modules, visual-studio-2019

I have created a new Angular project in Visual Studio 2019 using the "ng new" command.

I am unable to find the node_modules folder in my application.

When I click the "Show all files", I can see the folder, but with (-) minus sign in VS 2019.

Any idea on how to include it in the project.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason _why_ you want node_modules folder to be inside the application?

Comment: I have installed bootstrap in my project and want to include the bootstrap.min.css file(that is found in node_modules folder) in angular.json file. As the node_modules folder is not included, I see an error when I try add the file.

Comment: It won't complaint about it normally. Just checking, have you done `npm install`? 
Then, how did you add the bootstrap in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: Yes, I have installed bootstrap using the npm install bootstrap@3 --save. Also, the issue resolved now because I put an extra .(dot) in the beginning "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css". Still my friend was able to see the folder in the solution explorer, but I cannot see.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, node_modules folder is not included in the project. If you want to add it, you can right-click it and select Include in the project option